# How to read .DAT file and create array in php

Tags: php, file

I have `.Dat` File that have records like below

```
A079862464FEY201703210000257420170321005931902017.
```

Can anyone tell me how to read this file in php? I am able to read .txt file but I am not able to ready .dat file.

I tried:

```
$myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
$tcheckData= fread($myfile,filesize($file)); 
$tcheckEndOfFileArray = explode('||',preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "||", $tcheckData)); 
print_r($tcheckEndOfFileArray);
```

But I got a Internal server error 505. I tried

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["options"]) && $_REQUEST["options"]!="") { 
    $content = file_get_contents($_FILES["exampleInputFile"]["name"]); 
    print_r($content); 
}
```

But this also gave an internal server error.

Comment: `$content = file_get_contents($file_name)`

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI that would be also my suggestion, a `.DAT` file should be handled as plain text by php so `file_get_contents()` should return the string `"A079862464FEY201703210000257420170321005931902017"`

Comment: Is the `.dat` file just a simple text file, or is there more to its structure than a simple text file?

Comment: You are not getting any better at asking question here, and you are very bad at providing additional information when asked. Questions in the PHP tagged area get picked up very quickly normally, please **hang around for a few minutes to answer questions**

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hi I just got call, Yes please let me answer all your question by one one.

Comment: @TobiasF. I tried this  $myfile = fopen($file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
   $tcheckData= fread($myfile,filesize($file));



 $tcheckEndOfFileArray=explode('||',preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "||", $tcheckData));
     print_r($tcheckEndOfFileArray);

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes in that having data like this A079862464FEY201703210000257420170321005931902017

Comment: There is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43319462/edit) link under the question. Please use that to add information to your question. _Nobody can read code in a comment_

Comment: Ok so you tried that code. **What was the result?**

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I tried that code that I got internal server error 505

Comment: @TobiasF. I tried your code also but it gives me internal server error here is there code which am trying if(isset($_REQUEST["options"]) && $_REQUEST["options"]!="")
  { 
     $content = file_get_contents($_FILES["exampleInputFile"]["name"]);

            print_r($content);
             
      }

Comment: See that would have been **Very useful information to have put in your original QUESTION**

Comment: So we need MORE information about the `.dat` file.

Comment: **This is now getting annoying!** ___All this information should have been in the question before you posted it___ `$_FILES["exampleInputFile"]["name"]` **does not exist** on your server, its the filename that the file had on the users PC. Use `$_FILES["exampleInputFile"]["tmp_name"]`

Comment: There is a thing called [THE MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) **Please make it your friend** and use it before posting questions on SO

Comment: @RiggsFolly I will remember this in next time to put all.

Comment: Thank you. Remember, people wont hang around for 30 minutes waiting for a reply to a question. You shoudl also read back your post and ask yourself.... Could I answer this question with the information I have provided

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right I will remember this

Comment: @TobiasF. yes you are right it started working its my bad file should exist in my server then it work before I was taking from input file and then reading after that but first it should be on server.